# MYSQL select multiple times the same row

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT id, header, title, price_obm, packs
FROM obm
WHERE id
IN (2, 12, 10, 2, 10)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2, 12, 10, 2, 10)
```

Now, I need to output multiple times the same rows (2, 10) which may vary (it can be any number).

How can I do this?

**Output example:**

```
id | header | title | price_obm | packs
2  | head2  | tit2  | price2    | p2
12 | head12 | tit12 | price12   | p12
10 | head10 | tit10 | price10   | p10
2  | head2  | tit2  | price2    | p2
10 | head10 | tit10 | price10   | p10
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Nevertheless you can `UNION ALL` with the same query, but what is the point of doing that?

Comment: Please show sample data and output, as well as reasoning. Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @Antoniossss It doesn't matter why I need to do it, I just need it.

Comment: @Xriuk ye, It does, because I don't know do you really need to have such MYSQL query output, or you need to print it or process it or whatever. As if you know whitch row you need to repeat, just do it by processing results set, do not try to generate it.

Comment: @Antoniossss I EXACTLY need to output multiple times the same row, doing it in php would be too complicated

Comment: And I guess it is not the particular row or something. Do it on PHP side.

Comment: @Antoniossss I would need to do many cycles, but my answer is CAN IT BE DONE ON MYSQL?

Comment: NO, and i would leave it be just on NO but SO forces me to input more characters.

Comment: You're asking an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Quite often, there are better solutions if we know the problem you're trying to solve. If you give reasoning, your "How do I tow my pickup truck with a smart car?" question gets more helpful answers like "Siphon gas out of the smart car."

Answer (score 4):

Postprocess the result set using whatever programming language you are using to postprocess the data for presentation. Don't let MySQL do all the work.

A single query cannot produce the exact result that you desire, because the ORDER BY clause will always order the items with a common `id` next to each other.

Comment: Why? It's hard for me to use php to postprocess data, I need MYSQL to do this for me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `UNION` keyword.
You can found the example [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: Dunnow who, but maybe because I did mentioned it as comment?

Comment: This is not a very good answer. You could improve it by demonstrating the solution. In its current form, this should be a comment. Also, `UNION` would not be the right function. You would need to use `UNION ALL`.